# office-js #Excel Add-in taskpane

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, customtaskpane, jxtaskpane

I have created a excel web-addin. I have few drop-downs in my taskpane. when i save and reopen the excel sheet the data remains as it is on excel sheet but i would like to get the data on the task pane too.. can any one help

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need 2 steps:

- Persist the status into the workbook, you could use `setting API`. document and sample can be found at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.settingcollection?view=excel-js-preview)
- Load the status when initializing the add-in, you could use `Office.onReady()` API to read the settings and set it back to the UI element， document and sample can be found at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in)

Comment: Hi , If you dont mind can you please elaborate. For Example : I have my server location drop down in my task pane and im displaying it on my excel sheet cell A2. after selecting the server location I will save the excel sheet and will close it. When i reopen the saved excel sheet the server location should be selected in the dropdown .